# Bind Controls Position to Another Path

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a Path who's data comes from a LineGeometry. I also have a TextBlock that is created when the path is created. What is the correct way to get the TextBlock's position to follow the Path's position?

Comment: What exactly is the "Path's position"? When there is a LineGeometry I can think of at least three positions, the line start and end point, and the center of both. And how are you going to place (or align) the TextBlock relative to one of those points? You have to provide more information about what you're going to achieve.

Comment: @Clemens I am trying to position the textblock in the center of the points, which I can do using simple math. The start and end points are can be moved/dragged to an arbitrary position and I would like the textblock to update as the path endpoints do so.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways

- Contain the Path and TestBlock in a custom panel, and implement MeasureOverride and ArrangeOverride
- Use an already exist panel (Grid, StackPanel, etc.)
- Listen to LayoutUpdated of the Path object and then position the TextBlock using TranslatePoint method

Each way has its disadvantages and advantages, it depends on how your entire window is laid out and how dynamical are the path's layout changes

Answer (score 0):

The perhaps simplest solution would be to put the Path and the TextBlock into a common container that perform the necessary layout on the TextBlock. This could be a Grid:

```
<Canvas>
    <Grid>
        <Path ... />
        <TextBlock Text="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

---

You could also position the TextBlock relative to the Path's center by binding its [`RenderTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransform.aspx) (or [`LayoutTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.layouttransform.aspx)) to the Path's `Geometry` and use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) for the actual calculation. The converter would for example convert a Geometry into a [`TranslateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.translatetransform.aspx). Note that it does not even require the Geometry to be a LineGeometry. It just uses the Geometry's `Bounds`. You could however do any specialized calculation, depending on the actual type of Geometry.

```
public class GeometryCenterConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = new TranslateTransform();
        var geometry = value as Geometry;

        if (geometry != null)
        {
            result.X = (geometry.Bounds.Left + geometry.Bounds.Right) / 2;
            result.Y = (geometry.Bounds.Top + geometry.Bounds.Bottom) / 2;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

You would write the binding like this:

```
<Path Name="path" ... />
<TextBlock Text="Label"
    RenderTransform="{Binding Path=Data, ElementName=path,
                      Converter={StaticResource GeometryCenterConverter}}"/>
```

---

Note that the above example does not take any alignment of the TextBlock into account. If you need it to be centered or perhaps right- and bottom-aligned, you may need a more complex binding (perhaps a MultiBinding) or you may put all elements in a Canvas and set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` appropriately on the TextBlock.